# Store perfect forward values

Tags: c++

Is it unavoidable to make a copy of a and b in this code? I believe keeping reference is not possible, as some passed value could be a rvalue. Just checking whats alternative I could use..

```
template<typename S, typename T>
static bool TEST_EQ(S&& expected, T&& received, std::string const & error_msg) 
{
    auto a = forward<S>(expected);
    auto b = forward<T>(received);
    bool test = a == b;      
    if(!test)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed: expected:" << a << " received:" << b << std::endl;
         std::cout << error_msg << std::endl;
    }
    return test;
}
```

May I confirm the below version are copy free, right? if a rvalue is passed to the function, I believe only the argument tmp variable exist, right?

```
template<typename S, typename T>
static bool TEST_EQ(S&& expected, T&& received, std::string const & error_msg) 
{
    bool test = expected == received;      
    if(!test)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed: expected:" << expected << " received:" << received << std::endl;
         std::cout << error_msg << std::endl;
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `expected == result`? And should the parameters be `const`?. Regardless, `auto&&` creates universal references just like `T&&` does.

Comment: `T const&` and `U const&` looks like the better choice here. `TEST_EQ` doesn't hold onto the values passed in so there is no need to forward them. Not using forwarding references is also much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original case:

```
auto a = forward<S>(expected);
auto b = forward<T>(received);
```

`auto` will not be deduced to be reference types, so

if you pass in a lvalue, copy constructor will be called.

if you pass in a rvalue, move constructor will be called(if there is one defined).

To avoid copy or move, you can use auto&&(as mentioned by Daniel H in the comment):

```
auto&& a = forward<S>(expected);
auto&& b = forward<T>(received);
```

If you pass in a lvalue, `a, b` will be `S&, T&` -- no copy constructor call

If you pass in a rvalue, `a, b` will be `S&&, T&&` -- no move constructor call

> May I confirm the below version are copy free, right? if a rvalue is
>   passed to the function, I believe only the argument tmp variable
>   exist, right?

Yes, because you aren't declaring any variables inside the function. And parameter types in universal reference are always deduced to be reference types(e.g  `S&` or `S&&`)

Comment: To be pedantic: they are only copy-free if `operator==` and `operator<<` are defined on `S`,`T` with reference versions.  Of course, that's practically always the case, but it's not mandatory. 
 Example: https://tio.run/##dU9LS8QwEL7nV4wrSMuy4F7bjSDe9eDJ4zSd1kCahDwEKf3r1vSxLHbXQyAz8z2FtQehULfjeC@1ULEmOEnjgyPsnhhLN@/hzSUEQc/AxkpJUTBYd1kOHGpqMKpQXrbCaB/W4SGHHnyoi0KQc3A6we7F2G@pW0ANZsbspvWMIV2rEgY2lGfzZ2vVxrsyRoGx5DAYx/lqNwNzWIYeHIXoNAQXaRL8j7WEvKI1qDydg0gdoEOpsy8j63zKsqbCS2eopv/fnu8BXZiKhk9KBp1FJ73Rm7aJJhvIEDiHalHfCn1Ee3fNGoBSyJuE19TzFiO9teBjyYZx/BGNwtaPhwTjYr8/Hn8B .

Comment: @Piquan In that case, though, the copies are unavoidable and this makes no more copies than any other method.

Comment: @DanielH Absolutely!  I was just being pedantic about the question of “is this copy-free”, which is a distinct question from “does this minimize copies”.  But for sure, the “probably copy-free” version is real-world optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You typically only need to use `std::forward` if you’re doing something that can take advantage of rvalues, like move-assigning to a variable.  Here, you don’t need the assignment in the first place.

```
template<typename S, typename T>
static bool TEST_EQ(S&& expected, T&& received, std::string const & error_msg) 
{
    bool test = expected == received;
    if(!test)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed: expected:" << expected << " received:" << received << std::endl;
        std::cout << error_msg << std::endl;
    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: If an lvalue, is passed in to the first code sample in the question (say, `int i = 3; TEST_EQ(3, i, "i is not 3");`), then `S` or `T` will be deduced as an lvalue reference (in this case, `int&`), and will be `forward`ed as such. See [this post by Scott Meyers](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) on the topic.

Comment: @DanielH You’re right, of course.  For some reason, I had `std::move` in my head.  I’ve edited my post to remove the erroneous bit.

Comment: I figured out where that came from: I'd read `auto a` and `auto b` as `S a` and `T b` for some silly reason.  Thanks for spotting my mistake!